# Flutter - How to parse array items in custom widget?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, constructor

I want to map my data in a custom widget, but I am not sure how to parse them in that widget.

Here is a type of data:

[image]

Here is Widget who need to serve that data:

[image]

The problem is how to prepare a custom widget in the constructor class? And how to display data in a tree? e.g `this.module['title]`, or object notation `this.module.title` :)
Help!
I am a newbie in Flutter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a  class to handle your data.

```
class Module {
  String title;
  int id;
  String excerpt; // I'm not sure about types... Since i can't see the values
  String thumbnail;
  String content;

  Module.fromJson(data){
    this.title = data["title"];
    this.id = data["id"];
    this.excerpt = data["excerpt"];
    this.thumbnail = data["thumbnail"];
    this.content = data["content"];
  }
}
```

Then you use it where you fetch your data (obviously in onInit()).

```
List<Module> modules = List.empty();
  yourMethode(){
    YourApi.route().then((result){
      setState((){
        modules = result.map((module){return Module.fromJson(module);});
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Then in your custom widget

```
class ModuleList extends StatelessWidget{
  final List<Module> modules;
/// The constructor
  const ModuleList(this.modules);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     Module myModule = modules[index];
     return Column(
       children: [
         Text(myModule.title)
         // other elements here 
       ],
     );
   }); 
  }
}
```

Finally use the widget in the same widget you made your API cals

```
//...
child: ModuleList(modules)
//...
```